# Pointing specific users or OU's to specific DC's for logon authentication

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, security

I have around 200 users.

50 are in Asia, 50 in southern and Eastern Europe and around 100 in Western Europe.

I would like to point the 50 users who are in Asia to our DC in Asia, and currently it appears that they are authenticating to our European servers, causing a massive delay on that end.

What may be causing this, or what may resolve my issue?

Comment: No, @Davidw, this is what **sites** are for.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I would like to point the 50 users who are in Asia to our DC in Asia,
>   currently, it appears that they are authenticating to our European
>   servers causing a massive delay on that end.
>
> Does anyone have an idea on what may be causing this, or how to do
>   what may resolve my issue above?

You need to set up your sites and subnets in Active Directory Sites and Services. Once you do this, domain joined clients will authenticate to the closest DC to them.

Create a site for each location where you have a DC

Create the correct subnet for each site

Associate these subnets with the appropriate sites

Move the appropriate DC's to the appropriate sites.